# MySql: compare 2 tables within the same schema showing missing data from each table and showing the table it came from

Tags: mysql, join, union

Table A and Table B

same columns but different data

Need to find the differences and identify the table it was missing from

Need to use join and union of some sort

```
SELECT 
   b.areacode, a.accountno, b.accttype, b.year
FROM
   DB1.Table1 a
left join
   DB1.Table2 b ON a.accountno = b.accountno
    AND a.year = b.year
    AND a.areacode = b.AREACODE
    AND a.accttype = b.accttype
WHERE
  b.AREACODE < 24
  and a.accountno = b.accountno
```

Comment: Why do you "need to use join and union of some sort"? Is this homework? Please give a [mre] (Please read the link)

Comment: When you put a condition on `b` in the `WHERE` clause you're effectively turning this into `INNER JOIN`, so you won't get any of the missing rows from Table2.